# Ajax call returning error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

I'm developing a web application using HTML and JavaScript (jQuery), for database communication I'm using an .asmx web service in C#.

Deploying my app on local computer and local IIS works fine. The problem is that now I need to deploy my application on company web server and now is when every ajax call doesn't work and **returns error 401**. Something weird is that if I enter to the ajax call url (the asmx web service is displayed) and then return to my web site and reload the page now all the ajax calls works. For example:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://192.168.46.87/MyApp/ws_WebService.asmx/Login"
```

This ajax call returns error 401, after that if I enter to the url *http://192.168.46.87/MyApp/ws_WebService.asmx* my web service is loaded and if I reload the tab of my web page now ajax calls works fine.

This is my ajax call:

```
function CallWM(webMethod, JSONToSend, callBackFunction, extraData) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://192.168.46.87/MyApp/" + webMethod,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(JSONToSend),
            success: function (data, strErr, xhr) {
                callBackFunction(data.d, extraData);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                bootbox.alert("Error calling the server!\n" + xhr.statusText);                                
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
                console.log(xhr);
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
       bootbox.alert("Error calling the server!\n" + err.message);
       $.unblockUI();
    }
}
```

I already tried changing authentication type on server IIS, sending my credentials with the ajax call but I get the same error message, what other thing can I try or what could be the problem?

PD. On my local IIS works perfectly, the problem is now that I'm moving my app to a web server.

Comment: is your database is also on the same server or in a different server? which authentication you are using? which application pool identity you are using?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Database is on different server, Im not using an specific authentication I have my own login form however, on IIS is checked anonymus authentication and forms authentication, how can I check the pool identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I can fix this issue and here is the solution **in my case**.

On my application path I have an Web.config where I do not have anything related to authentication but I discovered that on IIS inetpub applications folder root there's another Web.config and on that file I saw that there is something about authentication, removing that solve my problem.